# Handling ReferenceError: geoip2 is not defined in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the geoip2 API to detect countries in my script.

I have written a script for success and error, however the error part never fires.

```
geoip2.country(onSuccess, onError);
```

I checked and saw that uBlock origin on my Firefox is blocking the geoip2 script. The error in my browser console is

```
ReferenceError: geoip2 is not defined
```

How do I handle this in jQuery and display a user to the message if I get the above error?

I am calling these scripts from index.html in the following way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script> 
<script src="/scripts/js/jqgp.js"></script>
```

In jqgp.js I also tried this,

```
if (geoip2 == undefined) {
    console.log("Please disable adblock.");
}
```

or

```
if(!geoip2)
{
console.log("Please disable adblock.");
}
```

But it didn't execute. I am using Firefox. By the way, everything works OK if uBlock is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
if (!geoip2){
    alert("Please disable adblock.");
}
```

Comment: `if ('geoip2' in window) { ...` would be a tad more explicit imo

Comment: Oh yes, I tried that in the jqgp.js. It didn't execute. I am calling these scripts from index.html in the following way <script type="text/javascript" src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script>
    <script src="/csharpbook/js/jqgp.js"></script>